# what's the diffence between using in the two cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, database-connection, using

I wanna to know ,if there's a difference between :

```
IfxDataReader ifxDataReaders = ifxCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    using (ifxDataReaders)
                    {
                        if (ifxDataReaders.Read())
                        {
                            item = (int)ifxDataReaders[0];
                        }
                        ifxDataReaders.Close();
                    }
```

---

```
  using(IfxDataReader ifxDataReaders = ifxCommand.ExecuteReader())
                         {

                            if (ifxDataReaders.Read())
                            {
                                item = (int)ifxDataReaders[0];
                            }
                            ifxDataReaders.Close();

                         }
```

Comment: the scope is different - in the first case you can use ifxDataReaders again and in the second it will be just local

Comment: You should see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386404/can-an-object-be-declared-above-a-using-statement-instead-of-in-the-brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>The tempting statement is to say "the first one won't dispose", but it will.</sub>

<sub>The second tempting statement is to say "the first one won't dispose if `ExecuteReader` throws an exception", but in this case *neither* will dispose.</sub>

If an error occurs in `ExecuteReader`, in *both* instances `ifxDataReaders` will **not** have been assigned so the `Dispose` call will never resolve anyway. As an aside, the call to `Close` is not actually required.

`Dispose` will be called in both instances and I believe in the same circumstances.

Variable scope will change. In the second instance, `ifxDataReaders` is scoped to the `using` whereas in the first `ifxDataReaders` can be used *after* the `using` (although, you'd be using a disposed object at this point).

The second form is preferred, to me it seems more explicit and is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have an object ifxDataReaders inside and outside of the using block.

In the second case you only have the ifxDataReaders object inside the using block.

Answer (score 1):

Only that the variable in the first one will be available to cause an ObjectDisposed exception if it's used without being reinitialised.

Answer (score -2):

In the second case `Dispose` will be called automatically.

Comment: In the first also, Dispose will be called.Sorry I forgot to post it.