# can I reuse an object that has been disposed through the "using" statement

Tags: c#, locking, idisposable, using

I am creating a class, say LockHolder, to simplify the lock requiring logic. It implements the IDisposable interface, thus I can use it like this:

```
using(LockHolderCreater.Create(lockObject, waittime))
{
    //do something
}
```

The Dispose method of LockHolder releases lockObject (through Monitor.Exit) if it has been gained (through Monitor.TryEnter).
That works fine if I create a new LockHolder object everytime LockHolderCreater.Create is called, but that would create too many instances of LockHolder. So I Write LockHolderCreater to maintain a list of LockHolder objects in order to reuse them. Now I am facing too problems:

First, when debugging, I found there are many such message as "A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll" in the output window. If what the "using" statement do is just to call the Dispose method, can I prevent this kind of exception?

Second, and more importantly, if I reuse the LockerHolder instances, at some early time after my application starts, a SynchronizationLockException exception would be thrown when I try to release a lock in the Dispose method, saying that "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.". I checked my logic, but I don't think it is possible that one LockHolder instance would be used by two threads at the same time. Can this be related with the ObjectDisposedException noted above?

**ABOUT the answer**

I don't get a direct answer of my question, but Marc Gravell's answer has made it less neccessary.

Comment: Why would it create too many instances? There is a multi-million dollar beast called Garbage collector, why would you need to write your own reuse logic instead? Do you have special requirements?

Comment: @nvoigt I am not sure whether I should trust the Garbage collector, I remembered a time when my application creates many socket connections (thus byte[] buffer), and until I decreased the buffer size, the memory just increases too fast. The maximum connections count are not too mush, just several hundreads, but some could be droped and new created. To solve that problem ,we implement another buffer of the byte[] buffer for reuse, and decreased the byte[] buffer size

Comment: You can avoid the allocation problem completely here - see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Should* you do it: probably not, except for very exceptional scenarios where you are in complete control of the types.

*Can* you do it: this depends entirely on the implementation - and you certainly wouldn't want to apply that at random to arbitrary types. If, however, the type is (as part of cleanup) returned to some pool and re-initialized and re-used, then yes it will *work*. But: you risk problems if the  `// do something` code leaked the reference somewhere.

> can I prevent this kind of exception?

yes: don't access an object after you've disposed it

> saying that "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code."

I wonder - are you perhaps using `await` here? or an iterator block? or something like that? If the enter and exit code runs on different threads, it will fail.

If your intent here is to minimize allocations of `LockerHolder`, there is a better approach: use a `struct`:

```
using System;

struct Foo : IDisposable
{
    public Foo(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Init: " + msg);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
    }

}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before");
        using (new Foo("Hi"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do stuff");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After");
    }
}
```

The `Main` method here compiles the `Dispose` using [`constrained`-call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which means it **doesn't box**.

Note that for this to work, the `LockHolderCreater.Create` method must return the struct itself - it cannot return just `IDisposable`.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to reuse the Foo/LockHolder instances whatsoever, and that make my second question meaningless?

Comment: And, why struct can minimize allocations than classes

Comment: @RussellYan a `struct` is a value-type; a `new Foo(...)` here *is not an allocation at all*

Comment: @RussellYan I explicitly said that it *was* technically possible to reuse the instances (as long as you control the types), but that it was not *adviseable* to do so. Or, indeed, necessary.

Comment: Your suggestion about the use of struct can do the work. But for curiosity, I am wondering how I can reuse the disposable instances, without the ObjectDisposedException being thrown. And yes, I control the types

Comment: @RussellYan if you control the types, then it is ***your code*** that throws the `ObjectDisposedException`. So: *don't do that* (but equally: don't try using the object when it is in an undefined state, either)

Comment: The `using` construct behaves rather obnoxiously with structure types; it copies the supplied structure to a compiler temporary variable when the block is entered, and calls `Dispose` upon that variable on exit.  I suspect the only real purpose of the compiler's "support" for `using` on struct types is to allow for the case where a type has to implement `IDisposable`, but `Dispose` doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to abuse the `using` statement. It is not intended as a general-purpose "automatic undo". It is only intended as a means to ensure the disposal of unmanaged resources like database connections.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the variable inside the using statement's control expression limits the scope of the variable to inside the using statement.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386404/can-an-object-be-declared-above-a-using-statement-instead-of-in-the-brackets)

Comment: Although not wrong, I don't think this answers the question in any way.